# How can I use PowerShell to identify List Content Columns that do not exist in the parent Site Content Type?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am looking create a PowerShell script to identify and remove site columns from a List Content Type that do not exist in the parent Site Content Type.

A 3rd party migration utility was used to migrate documents and it created duplicate columns in the List Content Type applied to the document library.

One set of columns is associated with the parent (Site Content Type) and the other set only exists in the child (List Content Type).  The library contains submitted InfoPath Filler Forms.

I do not want to remove and re-add the content type because I am unsure if I will lose data.

Comment: Hi @Brian, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)